How to move one file from a list and rename it?
I generate from time to time, in a directory, one file such as pi-hole-srv-teleporter_2024-08-27_13-59-16.tar.gz. But sometimes there are two or more following the same naming template (with different dates/times).
At some point, I would like to move one of the files to the directory /backup and set its name as /backup/teleporter.tar.gz. I do not care which file it is (and it will usually only be one single file, but this is not guaranteed).
Is there a clever way to do this pick/rename/move operation with the shell (bash) before I start reinventing the wheel with some Python scripting?

You could potentially use the script here and modify it to your needs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/845625/moving-only-the-first-file-from-any-directory-to-current-one

@Randomhero this is brilliant:) could you please turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Taken from:https://askubuntu.com/questions/845625/moving-only-the-first-file-from-any-directory-to-current-one
If you want to move only the first file in a directory, to the current working directory, you can use for, because it loops over files in an ordered way. Replace /path/to/ with the real path to the directory with the teleport files. You can test it first like by prefixing mv with echo:
for file in /path/to/pi-hole-srv-teleporter_* ; mv -v -- "$file" . ; break ; done

This will find the first file in POSCARS and simulate moving it to the current working directory. If it shows what you want, then re-run the command without echo to actually move the file:
for file in /path/to/pi-hole-srv-teleporter_* ; do mv -v -- "$file" . ; break ; done


mv -v -- move the file and report the action, then do not accept further options
. is the current working directory
break means break the loop after the first iteration, so it will stop moving files after finding the first one

